# Stripe Subscription JS issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I use the following code to create a stripe customer and create a subscription for that customer

```
  stripe.subscriptions.create({
                customer: customer_id,
                items: [
                    {
                        plan: plan_id
                    },
                ],
                trial_period_days: 7,
                expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
            }, function (err, subscription) {

 stripe.customers.create({
            email: email,
            source: token,
            metadata: {
                userid: userId
            }
        }, function (err, customer) {
```

I want users to subscription to subscribe to a 1 week free trial, Monthly plan (they pay after 7 days)

I am running into the following issues

1. Stripe does not validate the credit card number on prod. You can enter any credit card number and the payment goes through

Can someone please help?

Here's the client code

```
submit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ( this.props.planid) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({loading: true});
        }, 0);
        var planId = this.props.planid;
        this.props.stripe.createToken({name: "Name"}).then( token => {
            axios.post("/charge/process/" + planId, {
                token: token.id
            }).then(response => {
                if (response.data.status === "ok") {
                    this.setState({complete: true, loading: false})
                } else if (response.data.error) {
                    this.setState({error: response.data.error, loading: false});
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                this.setState({error: "There was an error.", loading: false});
            });
        })
    } else {
        this.setState({error: "Invalid plan id", loading: false});
    }
}


render() {
    if (this.state.loading) return (<Spinner />)
    if (this.state.complete) return (<p align="center">Thanks for purchasing! You can now access the <a
        href="/books">book summaries</a>.</p>);

    var error = "";
    if (this.state.error) {
        error = (<p>{this.state.error}</p>);
    }

    return (
        <div className="CheckoutForm" style={{width: "400px", margin: "0 auto", "textAlign": "center"}}>
            {error}
            <fieldset>
                <legend className="card-only">Pay with card</legend>
                <div className="container">
                    <div id="example4-card" className="StripeElement StripeElement--empty">
                        <div style={{width: "300px", margin: "0 auto"}}>
                            <CardElement/>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <button onClick={this.submit.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary purchasebtn">Purchase</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: None of this logic involves the card. Show us how you're generating `token` - that's where any validation would occur. It's also odd to create a subscription before a customer, as the subscription needs to be applied to that customer.

Comment: hi @ceejayoz can you please take a look. I added the code. I think the error is where I have `this.props.stripe.createToken({name: "Name"})`

Comment: Yes, that's likely your issue. Look at https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-token.

Comment: @ceejayoz please help me. People can't subscribe on my site. I'm really worried. I still can't get it to work.

Comment: @ceejayoz It turns out that createToken is returning an error. Do you know how to expose this error to the useR?